# How to create tear-off stubs at the RIGHT SIDE of a page

Tags: rotating, flyers

I want to create a flyer with tear-off stubs, as they are provided by the [stubs package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stubs). But I want the stubs to appear on the *right margin* of the page (in landscape mode). The package only seems to support stubs at the bottom of the page. Does anyone know another package or workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative to the package `stubs` using tikz.

It will fit a number of stubs according the page height and the chosen stub height. (11 stubs in this --landscape-- example).

It works also with a portrait page.

The command to use is:

`\rightstubs{<stub text width>}{<stub height>}{<front page text>}{<back page information>}`

[image: e]

```
\documentclass[11pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rightstubs}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]   
            \pgfmathparse{int(\pageheight/#2)}
            \foreach \y in {1,2,...,\pgfmathresult}
            \node [draw,
            text width= #1,
            minimum height= #2,
            anchor=east,
            font=\large,
            align=center
            ] (stub) at ([shift={(0,-#2*(\y-0.5))}]current page.north east) {#3};       
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \newpage
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]   
            \pgfmathparse{int(\pageheight/#2)}
            \foreach \y in {1,2,...,\pgfmathresult}
            \node [draw,
            text width= #1,
            minimum height= #2,
            anchor=east,            
            align=center
            ] (stub) at ([shift={(0,-#2*(\y-0.5))}]current page.north east) {#4};       
        \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    
\pagestyle{empty} % suppress page numbers  for a flyer
    
\begin{center}
    \Huge Simple alternative to the \texttt{stubs} package!
\end{center}
    
%\rightstubs{<stub text width>}{<stub height>}{<front page text>}{<back page information>}  
\rightstubs{4cm}{1.95cm}{ALTERNATIVE \\ to \texttt{stubs} package}{More information \\ More information}    

\end{document}
```

This code will add the stubs at the bottom of the page.

```
\newcommand{\bottomstubs}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]   
            \pgfmathparse{int(\pagewidth/#2)}
            \foreach \x in {1,2,...,\pgfmathresult}
            \node [draw,
            text width= #1,
            minimum height= #2,
            anchor=east,
            font=\large,
            rotate=-90,
            align=center
            ] (stub) at ([shift={(#2*(\x-0.25,0)}]current page.south west) {#3};        
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \newpage
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]   
            \pgfmathparse{int(\pagewidth/#2)}
            \foreach \x in {1,2,...,\pgfmathresult}
            \node [draw,
            text width= #1,
            minimum height= #2,
            anchor=east,
            font=\large,
            rotate=-90,
            align=center
            ] (stub) at ([shift={(#2*(\x-0.25,0)}]current page.south west) {#4};        
        \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

`\bottomstubs{4cm}{1.95cm}{ALTERNATIVE \\ to \texttt{stubs} package}{More information \\ More information}` will produce

[image: f]

Comment: This is great, thank you! I just had to replace `\pageheight` with `\pdfpageheight` for some reason.